# Multiple python virtual env

Tags: python, linux, virtualenv

Suppose i have normal system python 2.7 packages in system locations

Then i do

```
virtualenv env1
```

I install all requirements there

Then i deactivate that and do

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/env1
```

Then i do `virtualenv env2` and then install new requirements there

then i do this again

`export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/env2`

So my questions is

All the packagaes which are installed in env1 , will not be installed in env2 or env2 will install new packagaes.

I ahve problem where if i `pip install packagae1` while env2 is activated. it says requirement already met

Then i open python shell and do import mymodule. It says module not found. I can see that module was there in `env1`.

I had to remove that module from env1 and then install on env2 and then it work.

I want to know whay is that

Answer (score 1):

Have you activated env2 before installing module  ?

> source bin/activate

If you want to uninstall any module from virtualenv, then use

> pip uninstall module_name

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, do not change PYTHONPATH manually. 
Steps should look something like this:

```
[root@demo src]$ source /usr/local/env1/bin/activate
(env1)[root@demo src]$ # pip install blah
(env1)[root@demo src]$ source /usr/local/env2/bin/activate
(env2)[root@demo src]$ #pip install blah
(env2)[root@demo src]$
```

Comment: whats issue with adding PYTHONPATH manually. the reason i want to do it because some packaages  i ahve to install manually so i have one virtual env stored in snapshot and put in python path so that others don't have to install those whwich are not avaibalbe via pip. am i wrong in that thinking

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have not activated the virtual environment (lets call it  as `venv`) and installed the package system wide.

I suggest you to try activating the venv first and then proceed with installations in either of the venv.

You can activate venv using following code :

```
 cd ~/venv/
 source /bin/activate
```